# Why does the Iterator not "Move Next" in a for loop

Tags: java, iterator

I'm learning to iterate, and have implemented an Iterator on my 'CStickChart' Class using the following private property:

```
  private List<CStick> cStickCollection = new ArrayList<CStick>();
```

and then implementing the method to return CSticks:

```
  public Iterator<CStick> iterator() {
    return this.cStickCollection.iterator();
  }
```

Now when I try and iterate through it, I'm able to do so with the assigned localCStick but calling the next() method on the CStickChart Iterator doesn't do what I expected it to. I expected it to give me the next CStick in my CStickChart (hence when I call the getEPIC I was expecting it to give me the next EPIC along).

```
// Print the EPIC out of the Array using the iterator
for (CStick localCStick : testCStickChart) {
  System.out.println(localCStick.getEPIC());
  //The below line doesn't return the next CStick and I'm not sure why
  System.out.println("next EPIC is " + testCStickChart.iterator().next().getEPIC());
}
```

Please could someone explain why this is not the case (it always returns the first EPIC)

Comment: For one, the call to `iterator()` always returns a new `Iterator` unless otherwise specified. For two, why are you getting another iterator if you're already iterating over the elements in the enhanced for loop?

Comment: Something tells me your understanding of iterators is flawed. `Iterator().next()` won't return the next element *following* `localCStick`, it doesn't know anything about your `for` loop over `localCStick`.

Comment: I think you might be right Mattias. My experience was back in old VB6, and the closest experience I can draw was on the recordset structure (ADODB) but it appears they're not all that similar. I'm going back to the books and reading up on Collections, Iterators and such like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to use the enhanced-`for` structure.  The reason: an enhanced-`for` with an iterable entity [will use the iterator provided internally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), and will only ever advance forward.

This also means that any calls to a `iterator` while inside that loop produce an iterator that starts at the *beginning* of iteration.

So, with that, you have two options - both of which involve abandoning the enhanced-`for`:

- Use a standard `for` loop with indexing to advance backwards and forwards with the list, or
- Use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) as provided by `List` to move backwards and forwards in a very seamless way.

Here is an example with using integers - note that every time I advance the iterator I have to move it back to its previous spot so that I don't double-advance it.  Also, I have a condition to break out of the loop once we've run out of elements.

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    add(4);
    add(5);
    add(6);
    add(7);
    add(8);
    add(9);
    add(10);
}};

for (ListIterator<Integer> iterator = integerList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    int value = iterator.next();
    int nextValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        nextValue = iterator.next();
        // Reset the state of the iterator
        iterator.previous();
    }

    System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    if(nextValue != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("Next value = " + nextValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Makoto, this was a good and full answer, but Diogo's answer was slightly easier to interpret. Thanks for this description though

Comment: I appreciate the remarks, but I took a look at their answer (and ran it), and it does not satisfy what your requirements are.  Try to give my code another read.  If there's anything in particular I can do to clarify the above solution, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Makoto, I've read and re-read it. I think it makes sense to me (see my comment on Diogo's post to check that I'm finally getting it) - The only thing not entirely clear to me in this description is (I think) as a result of using a collection of integers rather than a collection of objects as I had in the question. In my example if I us 'int value =  iterator.next())' I think it returns me an object (and not an int)

Comment: I used `Integer` as a stand-in for your object.  Because `Iterator` is generic, you can bind it to any object you like and invoke object-specific methods on it after `next()`.  Here, I opted for an easy approach with just an integer list.  Your instance will return an object as opposed to an `Integer`, so feel free to substitute your object type with any occurrences of `Integer` or `int` that you see.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("next EPIC is " + testCStickChart.iterator().next().getEPIC());
```

This happens because in this line you are getting a new iterator in every iteration of the loop. Each new iterator starts from the beginning of the list again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting the top iterator of `cStickCollection` with `.iterator()`. I think you wanted to use the same `iterator` position as you're at in your loop, and `peek` at the next element. You can't do that with a `for-each` loop and you also can't do that with an `Iterator` in general (because they don't implement a `peek`).

Instead, you could use a traditional `for` loop on your `cStickCollection` like

```
for (int i = 0, len = cStickCollection.size(); i < len; i++) {
    CStick localCStick = cStickCollection.get(i);
    System.out.println(localCStick.getEPIC());
    if (i + 1 < len) { // <-- check that there is a "next"
        System.out.println("next EPIC is "+cStickCollection.get(i+1).getEPIC());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `testCStickChart.iterator()` inside of that loop, you create a new iterator object. So each call to `next()` is carried out on a new iterator object, returning the first object. What you want to do is to declare a new `Iterator<CStick>` just before the loop and use it inside the loop, like so:

```
Iterator<CStick> it = testCStickChart.iterator();
// Print the EPIC out of the Array using the iterator
for (CStick localCStick : testCStickChart) {
    System.out.println(localCStick.getEPIC());
    //The below line doesn't return the next CStick and I'm not sure why
    System.out.println("next EPIC is " + it.next().getEPIC());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Diogo, this was a really clear and simple answer with code that drops straight in, that enables me to understand it.

Comment: While this does resolve the issue (somewhat) of the iterator starting at the beginning every time, this does not actually get the next value from the iterator (relative to what was iterated on before).  If the naive approach is done (calling `next` outside of the loop on `it`), then a call to `it.next()` when there is no next will produce a `NoSuchElementException`.  This code is no better than what was originally posted.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The loop should actually be `while(it.hasNext())`

Comment: At that point, it's no different than the enhanced-`for` statement.  You could make this work but in its current state, it's completely broken.

Comment: So.... this is troubling because it works in the form you posted.... and I may have missed the point as to WHY it worked! Are you saying that it's still essentially running two iterators.... one which is enabling it to loop through each object (an internal structure that's moving between localCStick (initialised as the first object and testCStickcChart)) and then a second iterator initialised as "it" and not incremented as part of the for loop, but being progressed by calling the next() each time?